# Specify non equality in string comparison

Tags: excel, vba, string, if-statement

Within a procedure I am writing, I check all values of different columns of a table to be equal (or not equal) to a value.
Thing is I do not know in advance how many columns I will check and what values I will check and does not want to have to ask for another array of value (like 0 and 1) to specify if the value given in the first array is to be equal or NOT equal to the table's column's value.

Here is an example:

```
With Workbooks(path).Worksheets(sheetName)
    
    Set tbl = .ListObjects(tableName)
    i = 1
    For Each col In fColumn
        colRange(i) = tblSource.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    Dim flag As Boolean
    For i = 1 To .ListRows.Count
        flag = True
        
        For j = 1 To fColumn.UBound
          If colRange(i).Value <> fColumnVal(i) Then ' check if stored value is equal to specific value
            flag = False
            Exit For
        End If
        Next j
        
        If flag = True Then
            ' do something
        End If
    Next i
```

So fColumn is an array of string which contains the name of the column to be checked, colRange is the respective data range, fColumnVal is the value to be tested.
How I approached my problem is for each row of the table, I test the cell value of the different columns to be tested (names in fColumn) against the value of fColumnVal.
In theory that would work w/o problem. However, it could be possible that someone would like to find values which are different of the value in fColumnVal such as:
<<Find every cell which are different of value "Hello">>

My question is, is it possible to encompass the idea of check if not equal in the value of fColumnVal and not in the line of code of the condition. Something similar to the use of "<>" in Excel's formula which is equivalent <<to different of "">>.

If that does not exist I will simply add another required variable to the sub which indicates how to test the value.

Thanks.

Comment: You may use function **CountIf(range;"<>" & checkValue)**

Comment: So sometimes you might want to check for equality, and sometimes for non-equality?  I don't see how your code can know which one is needed if you don't somehow provide that information...